# Default Select option Angular 8 Reactive forms

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I want to get all my data from my API and set them as defaults for my reactive form. I was able to bind all the values using `ngModel`. I just don't know how I can do this with my `select`. In my HTML I am getting my 1st select option from my home service. The second option onward, I am using my category service to display all the categories. I did this so that I am able to have defaults according to the product I currently have selected. The main problem I am running into is that I want to bind the ngModel to the first option so that by default if I were to submit my form it would be the first option submitted. I have seen people use patch value to do this but my problem is I don't know how to do this with the data I am getting through my html because it's being displayed in the html not in the the ts file. Using `ngModel`is the best solution I could come with.

```
html

  <!-- Table -->
  <form  [formGroup]="updateProduct" >
      <p>
          Form Status: {{updateProduct.value |json}}
        </p>
  <div class="table-responsive">
     
    <table  class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>FullPrice <i id ="asc-desc1"class="fas fa-angle-down" (click)="SortPrice($event)"></i></th>
        <th>Saleprice <i id ="asc-desc2"class="fas fa-angle-down" (click)="SortSale($event)"></i> </th>
        <th>Availablity</th>
        <th>Supplier</th>
        <th>Discount<i id ="asc-desc3"class="fas fa-angle-down" (click)="SortDiscount($event)"></i></th>
        <th>Edit</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          
        <tr  *ngFor="let home of home | paginate:{itemsPerPage:20,currentPage: p} ; index as i">
        <ng-container *ngIf="editMode !== i">
        <td>{{home.id}}</td>
        <td>{{home.productName}}</td>
        <td>{{home.category.categoryName}}</td>
        <td>{{home.fullPrice}}</td>
        <td>{{home.salePrice}}</td>
        <td>{{home.availability}}</td>
        <td>{{home.supplier.supplierName}}</td>
        <td>{{home.discount }}</td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container *ngIf="editMode === i">
          
          <td><input class="form-control" id="id"  formControlName="id" [(ngModel)]="home.id" disabled></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" id="productName"  formControlName="productName" [(ngModel)]="home.productName"></td>
          <td>
              <select class="form-control" formControlName="category" >
                <option selected="selcected"  class="opt1" >{{home.category.categoryName}}</option>
                <option *ngFor="let category of categories">{{category.categoryName}}</option>
              </select>
            </td>
          <td><input class="form-control" id="fullprice" formControlName="fullPrice" [(ngModel)]="home.fullPrice"></td>
          <td><input class="form-control" id="saleprice"   formControlName="salePrice" [(ngModel)]="home.salePrice"></td>
          <td><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="availability"  formControlName="availability" [(ngModel)]="home.availability"></td>
          <td>
            <select class="form-control" formControlName="supplier">
              <option selected="selcected" class="opt1">{{home.supplier.supplierName}}</option>
              <option *ngFor="let supplier of suppliers">{{supplier.supplierName}}</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input class="form-control" id="discount" formControlName="discount"[(ngModel)]="home.discount"></td>
     
        </ng-container>


      <!-- if assigned index to editMode matches -->
      
        <td class="text-right" id="tableDataBtns">
          <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button (click)="editMode === i ? editMode = null : editMode = i" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updateProduct" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">
              <ng-container *ngIf="editMode === i"><i class="far fa-save"></i></ng-container>
              <ng-container *ngIf="editMode !== i"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></ng-container>
            </button>
            <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteProduct" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <pagination-controls class="myPagination" (pageChange)="p= $event"></pagination-controls>
  </div>
  </form>
```

```
ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../model/Product';
import { Category } from '../model/Availability';
import { Supplier } from '../model/Supplier';
import { Home } from '../model/Home';
import { HomeService } from '../service/Home.service';
import { SupplierService } from '../service/Supplier.service';
import { CategoryService } from '../service/Category.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms'
@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-product',
  templateUrl: './update-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-product.component.scss']
})
export class UpdateProductComponent implements OnInit {
  availability:boolean;
  category:number;
  orderBy: String;
  Ascdesc: String;
  page = 0;
  home: Home[];
  categories: Category[];
  suppliers: Supplier[];
  selectedCategory: Category;
  edit: boolean = false;
  public currentProduct: number;

  toogleEditMode() {
    this.edit = this.edit ? false : true; 
  }
    
  selectCategory (category) {
       this.category = category.category;
   }
  
   available(boolean){
  
    this.availability = boolean;
    }
  
    update($event){
      this.homeService.getByParm(this.availability,this.category).subscribe(data => {
        this.home = data;
      }); 
  
    }
    updateProduct = new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(''),
      productName: new FormControl(''),
      category: new FormControl(''),
      fullPrice: new FormControl(''),
      salePrice: new FormControl(''),
      availability: new FormControl(''),
      supplier: new FormControl(''),
      discount: new FormControl(''),

    });

// model = {id: null, productName: '', category: {category: null, categoryName: null}, fullPrice: '', salePrice:'', availability: false, supplier: {supplier:null,supplierName:""},discount:null};
// json = JSON.stringify(this.model);
constructor(private homeService: HomeService,private supplierService: SupplierService,private categoryService: CategoryService) { }
 

SortPrice($event:any){
  let icon = document.getElementById("asc-desc1");
  if(icon.className === "fas fa-angle-down"){
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-up";
    this.homeService.getByPriceAsc().subscribe(data => {
    this.home = data;
  });
  }else{
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-down"
    this.homeService.getByPriceDesc().subscribe(data => {
      this.home = data;
    });
  };
  
}
// model = new Newproduct(null,new Category( this.value,"name"),null,null,false,new Supplier(null,null),null);


onSubmit() {
  // TODO: Use EventEmitter with form value
  // console.warn(this.profileForm.value);
}
SortSale($event:any){
  let icon = document.getElementById("asc-desc2");
  if(icon.className === "fas fa-angle-down"){
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-up";
    this.homeService.getBySaleAsc().subscribe(data => {
    this.home = data;
  });
  }else{
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-down"
    this.homeService.getBySaleDesc().subscribe(data => {
      this.home = data;
    });
  };
  
}
SortDiscount($event:any){
  let icon = document.getElementById("asc-desc3");
  if(icon.className === "fas fa-angle-down"){
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-up";
    this.homeService.getByDiscountAsc().subscribe(data => {
    this.home = data;
  });
  }else{
    icon.className ="fas fa-angle-down"
    this.homeService.getByDiscountDesc().subscribe(data => {
      this.home = data;
    });
  };
  
}


ngOnInit() {
  this.supplierService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
    this.suppliers = data;
  });
  
    this.homeService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
    this.home = data;
  });
  this.categoryService.getAll().subscribe(data => {
    this.categories = data;
  });
  
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Dont use ngmodel together with reactiveForms. Use `setValue` or `patchValue` on the formGroup.

Comment: @AndreElrico I would like a example if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mix up the the Template Driven the Reactive Forms. You can read more info [here](https://blog.angular-university.io/introduction-to-angular-2-forms-template-driven-vs-model-driven/).

As you are using 3 APIs in the same view, you can wait for all of them to respond then do the logic you want. This can be done by setting the observables into an object (an array for rxjs < 6.5) and use the [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

```
const observables = {
  suppliers: this.supplierService.getAll(),
  home: this.homeService.getAll(),
  categories: this.categoryService.getAll()
};

forkJoin(observables).subscribe({ suppliers, home, categories } => {
  this.suppliers = suppliers;
  this.home = home;
  this.categories = categories;
});
```

After that, update the form using the patchValue:

```
updateProfile() {
  this.updateProduct.patchValue({
    id: this.home.id,
    productName: this.home.productName,
    category: this.home.category,
    fullPrice: this.home.fullPrice,
    salePrice: this.home.salePrice,
    availability: this.home.availability,
    supplier: this.home.supplier,
    discount: this.home.discount
  });
}
```

last thing, remove the `selected` and add a value for the options so it can select it after patching the value (It would be better of you have an id for the categories to set them as value)

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="category" >
  <option [value]="home.category.categoryName" class="opt1" >{{home.category.categoryName}}</option>
  <option [value]="category.categoryName" *ngFor="let category of categories">{{category.categoryName}}</option>
</select>
```

Now when you want to submit, you can read the values through the form:

```
const formValues = this.updateProduct.value;
// This will contains all the values, you can access them by formValues.firstName ...etc
```

For more info for the Reactive Forms, you can check it [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: I believe you mean that the initial value is undefined until the responses come. To solve this issue, you have two options: either add the safe navigation operator `?` for all the elements that are using any property from home like: home?.productName and home?.category?.categoryName. Or, you can add an `NgIf` to to the formto now show when the home is still undefined, something like: `*ngIf="home"`, and show a loader for the user

Comment: I have been fighting with your answer trying to understand and implement it for a little over a hour. I am just getting so many error in my typescript. here is my stack blitz https://stackblitz.com/github/RashellSmith/Dashboard-FrontEnd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fupdate-product%2Fupdate-product.component.ts .

Comment: I have really only used the `?` when making a class. the home in my ts file reference  the array home [] because of that I am not able to access the characteristics of the home object.

Comment: In `update-product.component.html`, you can see form values as `{{ profileForm.value | json }}`

Comment: So I got confused. Can you add what are the responses of the services so I can understand more? You can add them in the stackblitz as you are calling localhost so it won't work. Add them as dummy data.

Comment: Yes, I understand that it won't work what I am asking is if you can implement your solution in my code. I have spend hours upon hours trying to figure this out but I have haven't seen any one use  interpolated content with angular reactive forms. If you have a example I can draw form I would be eager to look over it. I get what your doing you explained it well I am just not getting it to work with my code that why I linked my stackblitz.

Comment: Did you try to add the `formControlName` to the select? `<select class="form-control" formControlName="category" >`? If the problem persists, I have no problem making it work with your stackblitz but please add the data of homes, categories and suppliers as dummy data (No localhost APIs, just static objects) so I can understand what is the current behavior and how to fix it

Comment: The problem is that making a dummy data would take hours perhaps the whole day rewriting my code I am not that desperate.  I want to avoid doing that. My ultimate problem is that  I can't even get your answer to work. the syntax is off that why I wanted you to plugin your answer so I could copy how you implement it in the code. it doesn't need to work it just needs to compile, so I could review it and see if it fails.

Comment: figured it out! your answer was correct its only because my values were  in a array of homes.